# Solution for allowing user sorting in SQlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting

By user sorting I mean that as a user on the site you see a bunch of items, and you are supposed to be able to reorder them (I'm using jQuery UI).

The user only sees 20 items on each page, but the total number of items can be thousands.

I assume I need to add another column in the table for custom ordering.

If the user sees items from 41-60, and and he sorts them like:

41 = 2nd
42 = 1st
43 = fifth
etc.

I can't just set the ordering column to 2,1,5.
I would need to go through the entire table and change each record.
Is there any way to avoid this and somehow sort only the current selection?

Comment: Try this: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

Comment: To clarify, do you want the user to be able to rearrange the rows INSIDE the database? And does this ordering need to be saved? You probably don't want to add a new column for this, since that would mean you can only store one ordering for everything that accesses that table (so if you have more than 1 user, you have problems). If you just need to reorder things on the UI side and don't need to save the ordering, then cache the DB query results and manage it from within the client side application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another column to store the custom order, just as you suggested yourself. You can avoid the problem of having to reassign all rows' values by using a `REAL`-typed column: For new rows, you still use an increasing integer sequence for the column's value. But if a user reorders a row, the decimal data type will allow you to use the formula `½ (previous row's value + next row's value)` to update the column of the single row that was moved. You 
have got two special cases to take care of, namely if a user moves a row to the very beginning or end of the list. In that case, just use `min - 1` rsp. `max + 1`.

This approach is the simplest I can think of, but it also has some downsides. First, it has a theoretical limitation due to the datatype having only double-precision. After a finite number of reorderings, the values are too close together for their average to be a different number. But that's really only a theoretical limit you should never reach in practical applications. Also, the column will use 8 bytes of memory per row, which probably is much more than you actually need.

If your application might scale to the point where those 8 bytes matter or where you might have users that overeagerly reorder rows, you should instead stick to the `INTEGER` column and use multiples of a constant number as the default values (e.g. `100, 200, 300, ..`). You still use the update formula from above, but whenever two values become too close together, you reassign all values. By tweaking the constant multiplier to the average table size / user behaviour, you can control how often this expensive operation has to be done.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways I can think of to do this. One would be to use a SELECT FROM SELECT style statement. As in something like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3...
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
    LIMIT n,m
) as Table_A
ORDER BY ...
```

The second option would be to use temp tables such as:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table_A SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT n,m;
SELECT * FROM temp_table_A ORDER BY ...
```

Another option to look at would be jQuery plugin like [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Answer (score 1):

one way i can think of is:

1. Add a new column (if feasible) or create a new table for holding the order of the items.
2. On any page you will show around 20 items based on the initial ordering.
3. Using the jquery's [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) you can send updates to this table

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with an extra column.

First, you could prepopulate this new column with a default sort order and then allow the user to interactively modify it with the drag and drop of jquery-ui.

Lets say this user has 100 items in the table. You set the values in the order column to [1,2,3,...,99,100]. I suggest that you run a script on the original table to set all items to a default sort order.

Now going back to your example where the user is presented with items 41-60: the initial presentation in their browser would rank those at orders [41,42,43,...,59,60]. You might also need to save the lowest order that appears in this subset, in this case 41. Or better yet, save the entire array of rankings and restore the exact same numbers in the new order. This covers the case where they select a set of records that are not already consecutively ordered, perhaps because they belong to someone else.

To demonstrate what I mean: when they reorder them in the page, your javascript reassigns those same numbers back to the subset in the new order. Like this:

```
item A : 41
item B : 45
item C : 46
item D : 47
item E : 51
item F : 54
item G : 57
```

then the user changes them to this order, but you reassign the numbers like this:

```
item D : 41
item F : 45
item E : 46
item A : 47
item C : 51
item B : 54
item G : 57
```

This should also work if the subset *is* consecutive.